# Google Sheets Loop over range

Tags: loops, google-sheets

How can I iterate through range in Google Sheets without copy-paste lines?
I have formula like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($B$2), 0, OFFSET(Vitamins_data_start_offset, MATCH($E5, Vitamins_list, 0), MATCH($B$2, Products_list, 0))*$C$2/Product_weight)+
IF(ISBLANK($B$3), 0, OFFSET(Vitamins_data_start_offset, MATCH($E5, Vitamins_list, 0), MATCH($B$3, Products_list, 0))*$C$3/Product_weight)+
IF(ISBLANK($B$4), 0, OFFSET(Vitamins_data_start_offset, MATCH($E5, Vitamins_list, 0), MATCH($B$4, Products_list, 0))*$C$4/Product_weight)+
...
IF(ISBLANK($B$39), 0, OFFSET(Vitamins_data_start_offset, MATCH($E5, Vitamins_list, 0), MATCH($B$39, Products_list, 0))*$C$39/Product_weight)
```

How can I simplify it to something like this:

```
=SUM_ALL($B$2:$B$39, IF(ISBLANK(X), 0, OFFSET(Vitamins_data_start_offset, MATCH($E5, Vitamins_list, 0), MATCH(X, Products_list, 0))*OFFSET(X,1,0)/Product_weight)
```

I tried to use SUM() with ARRAYFORMULA(), but looks like it doesn't fit here

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Map with both input columns:

```
=SUM(MAP(B2:B39,C2:C39,LAMBDA(bv,cv,IF(ISBLANK(bv), 0, OFFSET(Vitamins_data_start_offset, MATCH($E5, Vitamins_list, 0), MATCH(bv, Products_list, 0))*cv/Product_weight))))
```